# Database explorer tool for SQL Server 2012 using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, reflection

I am tasked with creating a database explorer tool for SQL Server 2012 databases using Entity Framework and ASP.NET MVC.

I have created required db contexts and I am able to get static queries to work. The current approach is very inefficient as it involves creating a controller action and a view for every table - this is for columns in tables etc.

I wish to have only one controller action and only one view to render paged records of tables.

I am able to get table names displayed using reflection on db context. 
The code I use is very simple:

```
foreach (var propertyInfo in db.GetType().GetProperties())
{
//every property here is a persisted entity

}
```

However I am not able to get records from the db context db set.

My design involves passing table name (Entity Framework entity name) as query string parameter.
e.g.

> http://localhost:8080/TableDetails/List?id=MyNamespace.Models.User_Info

The corresponding List Action method is:

```
public ActionResult List(string id)
{   
    ViewBag.TableName = id;
    //here I need to put up code to get first page of the table user_info
    return View(); 
}
```

The static List Action method would be:

```
    public ActionResult List(string id)
    {
        var rowsPerPage = 20;
        int? page = 1;
        var skipCount = rowsPerPage * (page ?? 0);
        var vm = new ViewModel<user_info>();
        vm.RowsPerPage = rowsPerPage;
        vm.Records = db.user_info.OrderByDescending(x => x.update_date).Skip(skipCount).Take(rowsPerPage).ToList();
        vm.CurrentPageNo = page ?? 1;
        vm.HasNextPage = db.user_info.OrderByDescending(x => x.update_date).Skip(skipCount + rowsPerPage).Take(1).ToList().Count > 0;
        return View(vm);
    }
```

Is there a way of querying Entity Framework context dynamically ?

Answer (score 0):

I won't suggest using Entity Framework or Any ORM to create SQL Explorer type of tool. I will rather use ADO.NET, will query System Tables, System Stored Procedure to query all the database objects.

I can imagic that Creating dynamic Data-Context is possible. But that will include lot of complexity of creating mapped classes during run-time using Reflection. And there's nothing an ORM system will provide you by default to achieve what you want.

Comment: Hi @GauravSharma, I am allowed to create Data-Context statically. So no issues there. design time built context also, allows me to conditionally hide one of the tables.

Comment: Well in that case, you just need to create a Generic Controller where you can pass your Model Entity as <T>, please paste one of your controller action in code. I will convert it to generic for you.